# JTree with multiple JPanels

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtree

I'm starting with programming in Java, and I want to learn.
The idea is to have a JFrame, then put a JTree and finally a JPanel.
Then new JPanel's independent, each with their respective components.
And that selecting some JTree node load some independent JPanel.

They like to do this in C #, but I have no idea java.
For example with a button in C # looks like this:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in panel1.Controls)
    {
        ctrl.Dispose();
    }
    panel1.Controls.Add(new UserControl1());
}
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in panel1.Controls)
    {
        ctrl.Dispose();
    }
    panel1.Controls.Add(new UserControl2());
}
```

Other example:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/Dorababu742/using-treeview-panel-control-in-windows-form/

Any idea?
Sorry for my English

Comment: for starters, have a look into the online tutorial referenced in the swing tag wiki

Answer (score 1):

- use [JTree](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html) and to returns `String value` from [TreeSelectionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#select)
- put [JPanels to the CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)
- selection acme from `JTree` returns String value as paramanter for [CardLayout#show(Container parent, String name)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html#show%28java.awt.Container,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: [there you can to find out all JComponents with their important methods](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/Catalog0240__Swing.htm)